# Best way to set the same screen transition animation across the whole app

Tags: android, animation

I was wondering is there a simple way to set the same screen transition across the whole app? I currently am doing this:

Calling

> overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

on every activity. In the anim files are below:

R.anim.slide_out:

```
<translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
      android:fromXDelta="0%p"
      android:toXDelta="-100%p">
  </translate>
```

R.anim.slide_in:

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

Your ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks a mill!

Comment: Make a BaseActivity class that implements the animations, make all your `Activity` classes extend your new `BaseActivity`.

Comment: I knew about this way, and it was one of the ways i was considering. So i take there is no other way like in the Manifest to do the animations like this?

Comment: The manifest approach requires you to edit it every time you add a new activity. So no, it's not the best/laziest way.

Comment: lol Laziest! i prefer using smartest :) Thanks for that!